# Convert PDF to PNG's with Freeware.Pdf2Png

Tags: c#, png, pdf-conversion

I am trying to split a PDF document of X pages in X png images using Freeware.Pdf2Png in C#.

First, I transform the pdf document to a FileStream:

```
seleccionado = new FileStream(ruta_archivo, Filemode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

where **ruta_archivo** is the path to the PDF file.

Afterwards I use the Freeware.Pdf2Png library to convert all the pages to PNG's.

I try it with several pdf: with a 1 or 36 pages PDF files it worked great but with a 446 pages PDF the converter only transform 271 pages:

[image]

I have seen the PDF with another viewer and the file is not corrupt (I can see every page).

Why cannot I get all the pages? Is there any size limit in the converter maybe? Could it be something about the creation of the FileStream?

PD: I know there are other libraries like  iTextPdf or PDFSharp that make this much easy, but due to legal stuffs, I cannot use AGPL or GPL license libraries, jut MIT or Apache 2.0 (like Freeware.Pdf2Png).

Thanks for your time!

SOLVED: The problem seems to be the massive use of resources. Despite using 'using' instructions (not enoug to work), I add:

```
Freeware.Pdf2Png.ConvertConvert(pdf_file_stream, page-number)
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

after every transformation and it finally worked properly. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: Consider english var names. Makes it easier to read and follow your code for non-your-language-speakers.

Comment: To the problem: you are using `ConvertAllPages` - is there a method to convert specific single or a range of pages? You could use those to batch conversion and especially prove that pages 272 and above are not broken in any kind or form. You don't seem to get any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: Yes @Fildor, there is a method to convert single pages (not for ranges). I used:

byte[] png = Freeware.Pdf2Png.Convert(pdf_file_stream, page-number); 

but I have the same issue, byte[] png is also null from page 271 onwards. Thanks.

Comment: Not a solution, but gained information ... not too bad.

Comment: PDF is one hell of a weird format. Your larger PDF might have a small error in it. A PDF reader may be more forgiving, where Pdf2Png isn't. Could also be a size issue. Have you tried with other similarly large documents?

Comment: Thanks @NPras, I thought it would be a corrupt file, but I tried to split it with iTextSharp and others on-line converters and they worked.